# Display a WFS service with OpenLayers 3. Define and add custom projection

Tags: vector, openlayers-3, projection, geoserver

I have a very simple question which I can not really find answers to.

I am working with OpenLayers 3. I want to display a WFS Service with a layer defined in GeoServer 2.6.2. This layer is defined with a custom reference system which I have defined previously in GeoServer. I show you this SRS:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=14.25 +lat_2=13.3166667 +lat_0=13.783333333333333    
+lon_0=-89 +x_0=500000.00004 +y_0=295809.17715 +k_0=0.999967040229754        
+a=6378206.4 +rf=294.9786982138982 +units=m  +no_defs 
+towgs84=0,105.5,197.2,0,0,0,0
```

OpenLayers library does not recognize this projection. I should define it before calling the WFS Servicek. I consulted many examples on the web page OpenLayers, but I can not solve the problem.

Someone could help me? Thank you very much in advance.